# Visual Studio Snippet Context?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, code-snippets

I've built a code snippet, but am having an issue with the context where it's valid.

If I am on a new line of code and enter my snippet shortcut, it appears in the Intellisense list.

```
public void DoSomething()
{
  // insert code snippet here
}
```

However, if I am entering my snippet shortcut after an opening parenthesis, it does not appear while all the stock snippets seem to, like the "do" snippet, which I've modeled mine after.

```
public void DoSomething()
{
  DoSomethingElse( // insert code snippet here
}
```

Is there a reason custom snippets won't appear after a paren, while stock snippets do? And is there a way to make mine show up after a paren?

Thanks for any help.

**Update:** 
After a comment from stack72 in an answer below, after the Intellisense list appears, I hit ESC to deselect anything else and then hit tab-tab. While my shortcut does not appear in the list, it does, indeed execute.

While I'm closer to the answer, my questions remain: why don't my shortcuts show up in Intellisense after a paren, and how can I get them to appear there?

Answer (score 1):

if you press control + k, x then you will see a dialogue box that gives you the options of where to load the snippets from

if you have saved the snipped to your vs2010 settings folder then it will be in my snippets - you should be able to table into that list and select from there

Comment: Okay, I can see it when I use <ctrl>k + x, and it inserts, so I'm closer. However, it takes 8 keystrokes to accomplish that. If I type in my expression by hand without the snippet, it takes 6. Is there any way to load this more automatically with the tab-tab?

Comment: you can set a keywork as part of the meta information in your snippet - type the word and press tab tab to get the information out. before pressing tab make sure there is no other terms selected (if so then press escape) - this should do it

Comment: stack72, unfortunately, this does not work. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171433.aspx, "The code snippet keywords are used by Visual Studio and represent a standard way for online content providers to add custom keywords for searching or categorization." They seem to have nothing to do with executing the snippet. HOWEVER, your suggestion of typing the shortcut, hitting escape, and then tab-tab worked. For some reason, my shortcut doesn't show up in Intellisense, but it will still execute. A bit of a hassle, but slightly more workable. Thanks.

Comment: im really sorry the name doesn't show up - but at least the word tab tab works :)